# how do I create an EntityManagerFactoryBean if all I have is a Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an environment where we have a Hibernate `SessionFactory` provided by the container, and I want to use Spring Data JPA, so, how do I do "wrapping" ?

It seems as though I need to at least implement (or extend existing) JpaVendorAdapter and/or `[Hibernaty]EntityManagerFactory`, but this seems to require tremendous amount of work like supporting properties, connection retrieval, etc, when in fact nothing of this is actually required as the SessionFactory is already bootstrapped for us

any advice is highly appreciated!